# Regarding the road setup

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have created a flash as2 car game in which the car is always placed at the center of the screen and where the driving lane is moving. My driving lane is about 50 times bigger than the stage. I would therefore (before doing this) ask you if it would improve the game performance if i split up the lane into smaller squares/tiles only showing the tiles when they are appearing at the stage view?

Cheers.

Comment: Is it enough to add a mask to the stage, or do i need to split everything into symbols?

Comment: A Mask may help, but I can't say for sure as I haven't done an AS2 project in about 8 years and don't recall how it manages display stuffs.   Is there a reason you're not using AS3?

Comment: Lazyness I guess. Old code I could reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I would use -- and it's a method borrowed from old 8 bit games for performance.

Instead of taking your clip that's 50 times as long as the stage and just turning pieces of it on and off, what you would do is come up with smaller tiles and use as many of them as you need for the width of the stage plus maybe an extra column or two on the trailing edge.  Wider tiles will be less tiles to move around.

Now you can move them all via script; if your game is already running a master loop or onEnterFrame, you can set up a sub-function of that which controls the road movement and have one loop that moves each tile for a set change in x coordinate (your speed).  Once they move off the visible edge of the stage, you can then bounce them over to the other edge of the stage where they are preparing to enter and just let them continue to slide to the side.

Also: if you are using vector artwork, try making sure the "cacheAsBitmap" property is set to true -- or that the box in the properties panel for the stage object is checked.  That will likely increase your performance as well.